# Qt ODBC driver crashes on QDatabase::open() OS X

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, qt, odbc

While trying to connect to a MS SQL database the app crashes.

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");

db.setHostName("test");
db.setDatabaseName("test");
db.setUserName("test");
db.setPassword("test");
qDebug() << "Is driver available:" << db.isDriverAvailable("QODBC");
qDebug() << "Drivers:" << db.drivers();
qDebug() << "Db is valid:" << db.isValid();
qDebug() << "Last error:" << db.lastError();

    if (!db.open()) // Crashes here
        qDebug() << "Database error";
```

I saw some posts where unixODBC and FreeTDS is a solution but I was unable to get it working.
The output of `qDebug()` calls is:

```
   Is driver available: true
   Drivers: ("QSQLITE", "QMYSQL", "QMYSQL3", "QODBC", "QODBC3", "QPSQL", "QPSQL7")
   Db is valid: true
   Last error: QSqlError("", "", "")
```

Comment: You specify "QODBC" but do you download the [module](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) ?

Comment: I'm trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database not to a MySQL one.

Comment: What does 'QSqlDatabase::lastError().text()' return ?

Comment: Updated the question with debug outputs.

Comment: Can u add lastError().text() . Because like you can see last error don't help us !

Comment: How do yours connectionstring look?

See the documentation at
[QSqlDatabase::setDatabaseName](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqldatabase.html#setDatabaseName) how to set a connectionstring for odbc.

Comment: @LandelinDelcoucq: The output is empty string.

Comment: @Mr.Gray: Doesn't matter because the user can provide invalid data. Calling open() should never crash the application.

Comment: All what you need to get QODBC work on MAC Seirra and MSSQL:
[QODBC troubelshhot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093807/qt-application-crashing-when-using-odbc-driver-macos/45491568#45491568)