# Qt application crashing when using ODBC driver (macOS)

Tags: c++, oracle, qt, odbc

My Qt application is crashing when i use ODBC driver to connect to Oracle database.
The issue is a stack overflow.
My code is

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSqlError>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSqlDatabase db= QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC3");
    db.setUserName("SYS");
    db.setPassword("oracle");
     if (!db.open()) {
        qDebug() << db.lastError().text();
     } else {
        qDebug("success");
     }
     MainWindow w;
     w.show();
     db.close();
     return a.exec();
}
```

The error that appears :
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7ZdK.png)

I'm sure that there's no problem with the code , because i've tried it on a windows machine. 
Also i did build the ODBC driver with qmake.

I'm new to Qt , i'm probably doing something wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: the screenshot you attached does not contain  any useful information. 1st check whether the app. at least loaded Oracle OCI driver libclntsh .

Comment: Hello , i will use QODBC driver , not the OCI one.
i did build the unixODBC driver as mentioned in the qt website tutorial.

Comment: OCI one is a must. unixODBC is a wrapper around OCI. QODBC is a wrapper around unixODBC. There is no other implementation of Oracle's TNS protocol available except libclntsh. 1st check whether our unixODBC connection works

Answer (score 1):

### Steps to activate/test QODBC on Mac OS ((Seirra) towards MSSQL or any other ODBC DB:

Symptom 1: Qt Run (Debug) application crashes (program unexpectedly finished/crashed).
Symptom 2: Qt Creator with pre-built Qt packages (MaintenanceTool).

Symptom 3: freeTDS driver (libtdsodbc.so) is missing after installing freeTDS packages.

Symptom 4: Qt built/configured before or with missing unixODBC.

1. Download and install unixODBC (**must be done before installing freeTDS**) 
   ([www.unixODBC.org](http://www.unixODBC.org)) / (Drivers) / (unixODBC-2.3.4.tar.gz)

unzip and untar the packages.

`./configure --prefix=/usr/local/unixODBC`   (be sure you can write OR sudo)

`make
sudo make istall`

2. Download and install freeTDS:
   (http://www.freetds.org/) / ( Quick Links) / (Latest Versions) / (Stable Release)

untar/unzip the package.

`./configure --prefix=/usr/local/freeTDS --with-unixodbc=/usr/local/unixODBC/`

```
make
```

`sudo make istall`

Note: `--with-unixodbc` will cause the driver (libtdsodbc.so) to be installed.

3. Unfortunately, possibly the ODBC plugin on Qt should be rebuilt:

   - If you are using the prebuilt Qt libraries, you will need to download sources using MaintenanceTool ($QTDIR/MaintenanceTool.app)
   - Tell qmake where to find the unixODBC header files and shared libraries (here it is assumed that unixODBC is installed in /usr/local/unixODBC) and run make:

   `cd $QTDIR/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/odbc`

   my case: `cd /usr/local/Qt/5.9.1/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/odbc`

   `qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/local/unixODBC/include" "LIBS+=-L/usr/local/unixODBC/lib -lodbc"`

   `make`

if that goes correctly: you will get complied QODBC new libs:

```
cd ../plugins/sqldrivers/
```

copy the new packages for example to :

```
/usr/local/Qt/5.9.1/clang_64/plugins/sqldrivers/
```

3. Configure /etc/local/unixODBC/etc/odbc.ini (you might need **root permissions** to mdify)

(No need to configure freeTDS):

- (**which port ? which version** -> Run
  `/usr/local/freeTDS/bin/tsql -LH 192.168.x.x`
- Create/Modify entry in /usr/local/unixODBC/etc/odbc.ini

  `[MYDSN]`

  `Driver = /usr/local/freeTDS/lib/libtdsodbc.0.so`

  `Server = 192.168.x.x`

  `Port = 51271`

  4. in Qt project:

  `QSqlDatabase mydb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");`

  `mydb.setDatabaseName("MYDSN")`

  `mydb.setUserName("name on Database");`

  `mydb.setPassword(" password on Database");`